# How do you make a dictionary out of 2 elements in each list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of lists that I want to make into a dictionary.  Basically it's a list of births based on date (year/month/day/day of week/births).  I want to tally the total births for each day to see in total how many births on each day of the week.

List example:

```
[2000,12,3,2,12000],[2000,12,4,3,34000]...  


days_counts = {1: 23000, 2: 43000, ..., 7: 11943}
```

Here's the code so far:

```
f = open('births.csv', 'r')
text = f.read()
text = text.split("\n")
header = text[0]
data = text[1:]
for d in data:
    split_data = d.split(",")
    print(split_data)
```

So basically I want to iterate over each day and add the birth from duplicate days into the same key (obviusly).

EDIT:  I have to do this with an if statement that looks for the day of week as a key in the dict.  if its found, assign the corresponding births as value.  If its not in dict then add key and value.  I can't import anything or use lambda functions.

Comment: You should read about the [`with` statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after playing around with the code and using print statements where I need them for tests, I finally did it without using any external libraries.  A very special thanks to Tobey and the others.

Here's the code with tests:

```
f = open('births.csv', 'r')
text = f.read()
text = text.split("\n")
header = text[0]
data = text[1:-1]
days_counts = {}
for d in data:
    r = d.split(",")
    print(r) #<--- used to test
    k = r[3]
    print(k)#<--- used to test
    v = int(r[4])
    print(v)#<--- used to test
    if k in days_counts:
        days_counts[k] += v
        print("If : " , days_counts)#<--- used to test
    else:
        days_counts[k] = v
        print("Else : ", days_counts)#<--- used to test


print(days_counts)
```

Code without tests:

```
f = open('births.csv', 'r')
text = f.read()
text = text.split("\n")
header = text[0]
data = text[1:-1]
days_counts = {}
for d in data:
    r = d.split(",")
    k = r[3]
    v = int(r[4])
    if k in days_counts:
        days_counts[k] += v 
    else:
        days_counts[k] = v

print(days_counts)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [`collections.Counter()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to track the counts per day-of-the-week. You also want to use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to handle the file parsing:

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

per_dow = Counter()

with open('births.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        dow, births = map(int, row[-2:])
        per_dow[dow] += births
```

I've used a `with` statement to manage the file object; Python auto-closes the file for you when the `with` block ends.

Now that you have a `Counter` object (which is a dictionary with some extra powers), you can now find the day of the week with the most births; the following loop prints out days of the week in order from most to least:

```
for day, births in per_dow.most_common():
    print(day, births)
```

Comment: `map(int, row[-2:])` is returning a tuple?

Comment: @pylang: no, but iterable assignment doesn't require a tuple, it requires an iterable.

Comment: I see, your slice unpacks into two variables.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Without using external libraries or if statements, you can use exception handling

```
birth_dict = {}
birth_list = [[2000,12,3,2,12000],[2000,12,4,3,34000]]
for birth in birth_list:
    try:
        birth_dict[birth[3]]+=birth[4]
    except KeyError:
        birth_dict[birth[3]]=birth[4]
print birth_dict
```

Comment: This one helped a lot..Thanks Tobey :)